# Pandas average row count per Day of the week

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

To get to that sum/count of rows of a weekday i do the following:

```
df['day'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.day_name()
print(pandas.value_counts(df.day))
```

But how can i get the average of rows per weekday if, for example there are more Fridays in the data frame than Mondays?
Or asked differently: how can i divide each count by the number of that weekday that have happend ?

To clarify: 
For example there have been 5 Mo,tue,wen,thurs but 4 fri,sat,sun () i would like to divide the counts of Mo,tue,wen,thurs by 5 and the counts of fri,sat,sun () by 4

The answer below is correct.

Comment: `df.groupby('day').value_counts()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want the number of days:

```
 num_days = df['day'].value_counts()
```

If you want percentages of days in the dataset.

```
 df['day'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Taking this a step further, it looks like you want the number of days in your dataset versus the number of possibly days.

```
 # Create series for days in your dataframe
 days_in_df = df['day'].value_counts()

 # Create a dataframe with all days
 start = '01/01/2019'
 end = '01/31/2019'
 all_days_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'datetime':pd.date_range(start='01/01/2019',periods=31,freq='d')})
 all_days_df['all_days'] = all_days_df['datetime'].dt.day_name()

 # Use that for value counts
 all_days_count = all_days_df['all_days'].value_counts()

 # We now merge them
 result = pd.concat([all_days_count,days_in_df],axis=1,sort=True)

 # Finnaly we can get the ration
 result['day']/result['all_days']
```

Comment: I think I see what happened there and I added some extra steps. I think you might want ratios.

Comment: I have probably worded my question wrong. df['day'].value_counts() gives the count per day of the week, but i want the average count per day of the week. For example there have been 5 Mo,tue,wen,thurs but 4 fri,sat,sun () i would like to divide the counts of Mo,tue,wen,thurs by 5 and the counts of fri,sat,sun () by 4

Comment: I don't understand the logic for the denominator off that fraction. Is it the number of days that occurred in a timeframe? If yes, see edit to answer.

Comment: our edits have overlapped thank you for a solution im gonna try it